# Is it possible to install AWS FreeRTOS into a PLC P1AM-100 Arduino Compatible CPU?

Tags: aws-iot, plc

I am about to buy a [PLC - P1AM-100 ProductivityOpen controller](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/productivity_open_(arduino-compatible)/controllers_-a-_shields/p1am-100) and I was wondering if it is possible to install AWS FreeRTOS on it. [SPECS](https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/p1amspecs.pdf)

How to achieve the install?

Comment: your question is not about IoT ... to be IoT related, the FreeRTOS would have to be loaded and functional ... perhaps it is more suitable for https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: FYI industrial use of PLC - P1AM-100 ProductivityOpen controller  is to deploy data into AWS-IoT core. We use AWS FreeRTOS to connect GreenGrass and devices to IoT-Core.  We can use it in robotics but the industry is using this device as an IoT piece from a long time now. But thanks for the link.